# Setting up revolut with Google Pay

Tags: google-pay, revolut

I am trying to set up my Revolut card with google pay but I keep getting the following error

"This card can't be set up to pay in stores. This feature isn't supported by your bank yet. You can try another card for in store use".

Why is this?

Comment: Google Pay only works if the bank of your credit card supports it. The message indicates that your bank does not support Google Pay. The only thing you can do is ask your bank why and if they plan to support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Revolut cards of Cyprus are not eligible for Google Pay per [Revolut FAQ](https://www.revolut.com/help/exploring-revolut/spending/paying-with-apple-or-google-pay/am-I-eligible-for-Google-Pay) and that's the reason for the message.

> During the beta release, Google Pay will only be available to selected users from Belgium, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, Norway, Poland, Slovakia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom and Singapore. We’ll roll out Google Pay to everyone soon

(Cyprus missing)

- Revolut cards of Cyprus are also not eligible for Google Pay contact less payment per [Google Pay FAQ](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/7454247)
- There is a [virtual card workaround](https://community.revolut.com/t/revolut-now-works-with-google-pay/50618/501) if you wish to try (see spider 623 post) .
- Interestingly, they are [eligible for Apple Pay](https://www.revolut.com/en-CY/help/getting-started/adding-money-to-revolut/with-apple-pay-or-google-pay)